# Replacing <br> with space in string using PHP

Tags: php, str-replace

I am trying to replace a `<br>` with a space within a string in PHP, however it does not seem to work. How would I go about correcting what I did to make this work?

The line of code that I have tried is the following:

```
    $keyword = str_replace("<br>", " ", getTextBetweenTags($html, "h4", "ctlAuthor"));
```

The string that is being returned in code looks like the following:

`Dörte Kreher<br>Humboldt-Universität<br>Institut für Mathematik`

The string that is being return to the PHP page is the following:

`Dörte KreherHumboldt-UniversitätInstitut für Mathematik`

The desired string that should be returned to the PHP page:

`Dörte Kreher Humboldt-Universität Institut für Mathematik`

Here is the getTextBetweenTags() function:

```
function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname, $tagid)
{
    $dochtml = new DOMDocument();
    $dochtml->loadHTML($string);
    $prgs = $dochtml->getElementsByTagName($tagname);
    $pcls = array();

    foreach($prgs as $prg)
    {
        if ($prg->getAttribute('id') == $tagid){
            $pcls[] = $prg->nodeValue;
        }
    }
    return $pcls[0];
}
```

Comment: Works here http://codepad.org/ucZCJMpj

Comment: getTextBetweenTags() is not a standard php function ...

Comment: getTextBetweenTags() is a custom function that was created to get specific HTML tags and extract the text between them. Added function to main

Comment: @Geroge then the OP should wrote down the function and its function ... as now he does it

Comment: What's your PHP version? It sounds like `str_replace()` might be failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the strings are coming from the NodeValues of elements within a DOMDocument, the HTML needs to be preserved. In order to resolve this issue, the line of code:

```
$pcls[] = $prg->NodeValue;
```

Was replaced with:

```
$pcls[] = $prg->ownerDocument->saveHTML($prg);
```

And then the HTML tags were able to be replaced with the desired output as follows:

`$keyword = str_replace("<br>", " ", getTextBetweenTags($html, "h4", "ctlAuthor"));`

Answer (score 3):

Try with a non breaking space html

```
$keyword = str_replace("<br>", "&nbsp;", getTextBetweenTags($html, "h4", "ctlAuthor"));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "__Unfortunately this did not work__"? When you write a question about an error, always __always__ include details of the error.

Comment: I do need to add that the returned string is going into the meta description of the php page.

Comment: Sorry Pedro, the returned string after using this still returns the same results.

Answer (score 0):

try this one, it´s replace all html code in the string

`$keyword = preg_replace("#<[^>]+>#", ' ', getTextBetweenTags($html, "h4", "ctlAuthor"));`

Answer (score 0):

<s>Why don't you use [strip_tags](https://php.net/strip_tags)? i.e:</s>

```
$keyword = strip_tags(getTextBetweenTags($html, "h4", "ctlAuthor"));
```

---

```
strip_tags
```

> Strip HTML and PHP tags from a string

---

```
string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )
```

> This function tries to return a string with all NULL bytes, HTML and
>   PHP tags stripped from a given `str`. It uses the same tag stripping
>   state machine as the fgetss() function.

https://php.net/strip_tags

---

Update based on your comments:

```
$string = "Dörte Kreher<br>Humboldt-Universität<br>Institut für Mathematik";
$notags =  preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', ' ', $string );
echo $notags;
```

Output:

> Dörte Kreher Humboldt-Universität Institut für Mathematik

Comment: I attempted the strip_tags, however the string is still returning with the tag gone but the words combined together, Could there be a underlying problem because the string that is being used comes from a DOMDocument?

Comment: I don't think so, I've updated my answer, try it out.

Comment: The DOMDocument, when I get the nodeValue (i.e. $pcls[] = $prg->NodeValue), the nodeValue is being returned without the `<br>` tags. So the issue is with that. I did try what you suggested as it was suggested in another answer within this post but I was getting the same result which now is due to the DOMDocument

Comment: @mattgcon I'm confused :)) So, if the `NodeValue` doesn't have `<br>`tags why do you need to remove them ?

Comment: I need to ensure that the words that are originally separated by the `<br>` tags are kept separated, and since the NodeValue doesn't have those tags there. I am going to need to either find out how to preserve the tags when I get the node value and figure another way around this.